# Ionic App - HTML5 video overlay play buttons are blurry in iOS 9

Tags: ios, html, ionic-framework

My ionic app has four locally hosted videos and the last two "play buttons" show up blurry on devices running iOS 9, but not iOS 8. I also tested on an iPad Air and only the last play button is blurry.

When I click a blurry play button the device opens the video in the device's default video player. When I click "done" to exit full screen the play button is no longer blurry, but now a different play button is blurry. Frustrating.

```
<ion-content scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true" class="padding has-subheader">
<div class="item item-divider">VFD Overview</div>
    <div class="card">
        <ion-item>
            <div class="video-container">
                <video controls poster="img/vfd_thumbnail.jpg">
                    <source src="vids/VFD_Overview_FINAL.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
<div class="item item-divider">VFD Basics</div>
    <div class="card">
        <ion-item>
            <div class="video-container">
                <video controls poster="img/basics_thumbnail.jpg">
                    <source src="vids/VFD_Basics_v2.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
<div class="item item-divider">Dynamic Braking</div>
    <div class="card">
        <ion-item>
        <div class="video-container">
            <video controls poster="img/braking_thumbnail.jpg">
                <source src="vids/VFD_Braking_v1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
            </video>
        </div>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
<div class="item item-divider">PID Control</div>
    <div class="card">
        <ion-item>
            <div class="video-container">
                <video controls poster="img/pid_thumbnail.jpg">
                    <source src="vids/VFD_PID_v1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
```

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
/*padding-bottom: 30%;*/
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
.video-container video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyf33.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).